# ajax.reponse question

Tags: jquery

i have this piece of code

```
ajax.ondone = function(data) {

   document.getElementById('id').setInnerFBML(data);

}
```

i would like to know if it is possible to know the size of parameter "data", i tried data.size and data.length without success
any help!!!

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

The answer might be "you can't". If (as it appears) `data` is an FBJS js-string object, it's not a JS string, and isn't built to be examined as such.